# Update wxPython grid in real time

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I am extracting data from a huge log and then updating the entry in wxPython grid. with the code I have I can see the window only after operation is complete, it takes 5 mins to complete the operation. Is there any way to update and see the data on grid from time = 0 itself.
I tried:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as  gridlib
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        ##
        # constructor to create the basic frame
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tool")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        rows = 4
        column = 600000
        self.grid.CreateGrid(column, rows)
        self.count = 0
        # change a couple column labels
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(0, "Timestamp")
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(1, "CMD")
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(2, "Address")
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(3, "Data")

        # Few More operations to calculate CMD,Timestamp field


        for i in range(10**5):
            self.count += 1
            self.grid.SetCellValue(self.count,1,'CMD4')
            self.grid.SetCellValue(self.count,0,str(self.count))
            self.grid.SetCellValue(self.count, 2, "Extracted Address")
            self.grid.SetCellValue(self.count, 3, "Extracted Data")
        # change the row labels

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wx.Yield()` to hand control back to the main loop.
Here I use `divmod` to get every 1000th iteration and call `wx.Yield`.
I also use `MoveCursorDownBlock` to allow you to visually follow the updating grid.
You may wish to remove or amend this, as it will slow down the execution of your program.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        ##
        # constructor to create the basic frame
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tool")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        rows = 4
        column = 100001
        self.grid.CreateGrid(column, rows)
        self.count = 0
        # change a couple column labels
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(0, "Timestamp")
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(1, "CMD")
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(2, "Address")
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(3, "Data")

        # Few More operations to calculate CMD,Timestamp field

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()
        for i in range(10**5):
            self.count += 1
            self.grid.SetCellValue(self.count,1,'CMD4')
            self.grid.SetCellValue(self.count,0,str(self.count))
            self.grid.SetCellValue(self.count, 2, "Extracted Address")
            self.grid.SetCellValue(self.count, 3, "Extracted Data")
            quo,rem = divmod(self.count,1000)
            if rem == 0:
                self.grid.MoveCursorDownBlock(expandSelection=False)
                wx.Yield()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with me. Till my operation is complete, it shows blank frame only(able to see with your code update). Only after that it shows grid.

Comment: Are you saying that your amended code does not work or that the code I supplied does not work, when run on its own?

Comment: The code you modified is itself not working as expected on my system.

Comment: Can be specific about what happens. This runs happily on Linux wxpython '3.0.2.0 gtk2 (classic)' Try commenting out the `self.grid.MoveCursorDownBlock` line

Comment: I am working on windows7 and wxPython 4.0.0a3. The Frame goes into 'Not Responding' mode till the operation is complete.

Comment: Insert a `print self.count` statement after the `wx.Yield()`. Does it count in thousands as the code runs?

Comment: `wx.Yield()` Deprecated since version 4.0.0: This function is kept only for backwards compatibility. Please use the wx.AppConsole.Yield method instead in any new code.

Comment: the GUI is updating now. But its freezes sometime. Guess I need to implement multi threading to make my GUI more responsive.